# LESS - Using a Guard on a Nested Mixin

Tags: css, less

I'm working on a set of buttons using LESS and I've run into a situation which I cannot seem to find a solution. Basically, I have a mixin that I'm applying to the `.button` class which has the normal state and a hover state declared within the mixin itself.

Now, the problem is that I want to add a condition so that I'm not forced to apply the `&:hover` declaration in the mixin so I've tried setting a default value to the `@check` variable and using the `when (@check)` in the `:hover` state but this produces an error.

I've dumbed this down a little bit from my original block but basically this represents what I want to do but can't seem to find the proper method in achieving.

```
._mixin (@color: red, @check: true) {
    background: @color;

    &:hover() when (@check) { // tried &:hover(@check) when (@check) as well
       background: darken(@color, 10%);
    }
}

.button {

    ._mixin(#333);

    &.disabled {
        ._mixin(#333, false);
    }    

}
```

How can I set up the mixin to exclude the `:hover` state on demand, for instance, when the `.button.disabled` is applied to an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is declare the mixin twice, once for all styles that should be applied, and once for all styles that need the guard:

```
//these styles are always applied when ._mixin is used
._mixin (@color: red, ...) {
    background: @color;
}
//these styles are applied only when the second parameter is true
._mixin (@color: red, true) {
    &:hover {
        background: darken(@color, 10%);
    }
}

.button {
    ._mixin(#333);

    &.disabled {
        ._mixin(#333, false);
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an inner mixin which has a guard on it:

```
._mixin (@color: red, @guard: true) {
    background: @color;
    //catchall for when the guard doesn't match
    .inner() {}
    //set your styles that you want to match in a guarded inner mixin
    .inner() when (@guard) {
      &:hover {
        background: darken(@color, 10%);
      }
    }
    //apply the inner mixin to the current mixin
    .inner;
}
```

Comment: I figured that I would have to do an extra step somewhere to get this to work but I wasn't sure what it was. I ended up building off of your alternative suggestion and it appears to be working as planned. Thanks.